# Clear textinput post clicking the button

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to clear the tectinput after clicking the button. I tried with below code but does not work.
Open the application and fill the textinput. But after clicking the button, it does not clear

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
  
runApp(
  list(
    ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                           fluidRow(
                             column(8, align="center", offset = 2,
                                    # selectInput("sdf","Asdf", choices = c(1,2), selected = NULL),
                                    textInput("string", label="Input",value = "", width = "100%"),
                                    tags$style("#string { height: 50px; width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size: 15px; display: block;}")
                             )
                           ),
                           fluidRow(
                             column(6, align="center", offset = 3,
                                    actionButton("button",label = "Clear"),
                                    tags$style(type='text/css', "#button { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 100%; font-size: 30px;}")
                             )
                           )
    )
    ), server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      
      observeEvent(input$button,{
        shinyjs::runjs("document.getElementById('string').reset();")
      })
      
    })))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `updateTextInput`?:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

runApp(list(ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
            fluidRow(
              column(
                8,
                align = "center",
                offset = 2,
                # selectInput("sdf","Asdf", choices = c(1,2), selected = NULL),
                textInput(
                  "string",
                  label = "Input",
                  value = "",
                  width = "100%"
                ),
                tags$style(
                  "#string { height: 50px; width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size: 15px; display: block;}"
                )
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              column(
                6,
                align = "center",
                offset = 3,
                actionButton("button", label = "Clear"),
                tags$style(
                  type = 'text/css',
                  "#button { vertical-align: middle; height: 50px; width: 100%; font-size: 30px;}"
                )
              )
            ))
), server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "string", value = "")
  })
})))
```